# How to set Secure attribute to csfcfc cookie in Glassfish?

Tags: cookies, java

After a vulnerabilities scan, I found that the `csfcfc` cookie does not have the `Secure` attribute.  `JSESSIONID` has `httpOnly` and `Secure` attributes. Is there a way to force it?

I found [an answer for JBoss](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/4005341) but can't find anything about Glassfish.

This is the session-config in my web.xml:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        60
    </session-timeout>
    <cookie-config>
        <http-only>true</http-only>
        <secure>true</secure>
    </cookie-config>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
```

Comment: Configuration in web.xml should not be server specific. I would expect this to work in Glassfish too. Just have a try.